# Create a git-repo using only the terminal

Tags: git, github

Assume I have a local folder called `Test` and I want that as a repo on github. Is there a way to do this purely using the terminal i.e without opening github, manually create a repo and push it to that?

Something like

```sh
git init
git add ReadMe.txt
git commit -m"initial commit"
git <create repo with this git account>
git <push to the created repo above>
```

such that there now on my github user is a repo with the name `Test` containing the `ReadMe.txt`

(I have added the SSH key)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+create+repository+command+line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must do something on GitHub, to create the repository there.  This can be as simple as telling GitHub "create an empty repository under my GitHub account", but there's no *Git* command to do this: GitHub require you to access some web on their site, set some parameters, and send a request.

You can do this through the `curl` program, if you have that installed.  See, e.g., https://gist.github.com/btoone/2288960.  If you don't have `curl` installed, most modern programming languages have packaged routines for doing web operations (e.g., Python's `requests` library), but it will usually take at least a few lines of code.

Once the GitHub-side repository exists—you can create this at any point, before or after doing command-line commands to create and manipulate your local repository—it's just a matter of telling your local repository how to access the GitHub repository:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/your-account/your-repo.git
```

for instance, assuming you'd like to use the standard name `origin`.  Then:

```
git push origin master branch1 branch2
```

or:

```
git push --all origin
```

will send the appropriate commits and ask the Git repository at GitHub to set its branch name(s) as requested on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub is outside the scope of git itself, and there are no github specific commands in git.

However, there is [hub](https://hub.github.com/) "*an extension to command-line git that helps you do everyday GitHub tasks without ever leaving the terminal*". In particular, one such "*everyday GitHub task*" is [hub create](https://hub.github.com/hub-create.1.html).